# Firebase auth anonymous login not responding when screen locked

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase auth working perfectly and `addOnCompleteListener, addOnFailureListener, addOnSuccessListener` events fired after successful anonymous login. But when I installed app using AndroidStudio and unlock screen after installation and app in running mode Firebase Auth never respond and stuck. Following event never fired when Android Studio launches app and triggered following code in activity while phone locked:

```
task.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Anonymous signInAnonymously:complete");
    }
});
task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
});
task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Anonymous signInAnonymously:success");
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
    }
});
```

If I install and run my application from AndroidStudio with unlocked phone its working fine.

Is it normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the version of Firebase you are using.

Try to use the latest one for compatibility.

Also make sure you add Firebase from the Firebase Assistant, which adds all the required code.

The service require the SHA? Make sure the Debug key (default usually) and Production key SHA are added and the JSON file is added to the project.